# Parallel Nsight 2.2 not working with Optimus (I think)

Tags: visual-studio, nvidia, nsight

I bough a new notebook this weekend and began to install all my development software. Im using:

- Windows 8
- nVIDIA GeForce Driver 306.97
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, 10.0.3
- nVIDIA Parallel NSight 2.2.0.12313 (+ CUDA Toolkit 4.2)
- Microsoft DirectX SDK June 2010
- nVIDIA DirectX 11 SDK
- nVIDIA DirectX 10 SDK

The problem started when I tried to use the Shader Debugger. I tested most of the Microsoft's examples for DirectX 10 and 11 and they crashed before any window appear on the screen, the same happened with nVIDIA ones. Windows log reports this (sorry it's in portuguese):

```
Nome do aplicativo com falha: HDAO10.1.exe, versão: 0.0.0.0, carimbo de data/hora: 0x50c75043
Nome do módulo com falha: Nvda.Graphics.Interception.100.dll, versão: 0.0.0.0, carimbo de data/hora: 0x509c20dc
Código de exceção: 0xc0000005
Deslocamento da falha: 0x006eb3f0
```

I didn't suspect Optimus at first because the examples are running normally on the Visual Studio debugger and even shows "GeForce GTX 660M" as the graphics adapter. I also ran a CUDA debugging session on a cuBLAS program I have and everything went OK, I profiled the program with NSight Analysis and also no problem, every possible statistics available for GK architecture was there.

The interesting part of the problem appeared when I tried to run a DirectX 9 example, although it worked, the NSight Monitor accused the following: "Not all NSight features are supported on non-NVIDIA GPUs", which leads me to believe that it's related to the integrated GPU. The problem is that the DirectX 9 example, as before, clearly shows "GeForce GTX 660M" as the graphics adapter.

I've seen similar threads on both NVidia forums and here, but they are unsolved and abandoned. I really don't know exactly the source of the problem, if it is Optimus or Windows 8 related since I can't find any conclusive discussion about the topic. I would like to know if anyone came up with a solution or, at least, an explanation for this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Optimus target is not supported by Nsight Graphics debugging. Windows 8 is not officially supported by current version also.  For you, Optimus is the reason.

Comment: Which is odd since Optimus is in the compatibility list for, at least, the Direct3D Graphics Inspector. https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-requirements

Comment: Alright, that information is wrong.  It used to work in some way.